# How to add values of two arrays that are different sizes in length?

Tags: swift

If I have two int arrays such as

```
var array1 = [1,2,3]
var array2 = [1,2,3,5]
```

I'd like to be able to add the first element of the first array with the first element of the second array, and so on. However if an array has a different length than the other I'd like to keep the element that was not added in the return array. For this example my return array would be `[2,4,6,5]`.

I tried using `zip(array1,array2).map(+)` but it would exclude the 5 from array2.

Comment: "I tried using zip(array1,array2).map(+) but it would exclude the 5 from array2" And what about a manual for loop?

Comment: Although SO is not a code writing service, I do appreciate that you took SOME time to actually ask the question and attempt a solution. In the future, it is more appropriate to come up with multiple attempts (especially an easy task such as this) if at all possible. `zip`ing is obviously not the ONLY solution; others would be more inclined to help if you exhaustively tried all solutions that you could think of.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
func combine2Arrays(array1:[Int], array2:[Int]) -> [Int] {
    var finalArray:[Int] = []
    let maxSize = max(array1.count, array2.count)
    
    for i in 0..<maxSize {
        let valToAdd1 = (array1.count > i ? array1[i] : 0)
        let valToAdd2 = (array2.count > i ? array2[i] : 0)
        let finalVal = valToAdd1 + valToAdd2
        finalArray.append(finalVal)
    }
    return finalArray
}

print(combine2Arrays(array1: [1,2,3], array2: [1,2,3,5]))
```

OR

```
func combine2Arrays(array1:[Int], array2:[Int]) -> [Int] {
    var finalArray:[Int] = zip(array1,array2).map(+)
    let largerArray = array1.count > array2.count ? array1 : array2
    let smallerArray = array1.count > array2.count ? array2 : array1
    let min = smallerArray.count
    let max = largerArray.count
    for i in min..<max {
        finalArray.append(largerArray[i])
    }
    return finalArray
}

print(combine2Arrays(array1: [1,2,3], array2: [1,2,3,5]))
```

Comment: I don't think your critique of the question is justified: this is a valid question, absolutely suitable for SO.

Comment: I disagree - he didn't show his code for his solution - only stated an attempt at it. Additionally, this is almost as if someone posted a question and provided skeleton code for a homework problem. This question definitely needs to include their attempts, providing their code, so we can reproduce their problem. As it is stated at this editing stage, it is a "I have this problem - here is the skeleton code - I need you to code this". As I gave him credit for his parts that he DID complete, I noted it could be more SO appropriate - if you would like, I can include the SO question guide @KirilS.

Comment: Everyone is entitled to their opinion. Except you are also violating the SO rules: your opinion about the question doesn't belong in the answer. Things like that belong in the comments section under the question.

Answer (score 7):

After adding the elements at the index positions which are common to both arrays (what you already did with `zip` and `map`) just append the remaining  elements from both arrays (using `append(contentsOf:)`  and `dropFirst`):

```
let array1 = [1, 2, 3]
let array2 = [1, 2, 3, 5]

var combined = zip(array1, array2).map(+)
let commonCount = combined.count
combined.append(contentsOf: array1.dropFirst(commonCount))
combined.append(contentsOf: array2.dropFirst(commonCount))

print(combined) // [2, 4, 6, 5]
```

Comment: Very elegant approach

Answer (score 0):

```swift
AnySequence(zip: (1...3, [1, 2, 3, 5])).map {
  Optional($0).map(+) ?? firstNonNil($0)!
}
```

```swift
public extension AnySequence {
  /// Like `zip`, but with `nil` elements for the shorter sequence after it is exhausted.
  init<Sequence0: Sequence, Sequence1: Sequence>(
    zip zipped: (Sequence0, Sequence1)
  ) where Element == (Sequence0.Element?, Sequence1.Element?) {
    self.init(
      sequence(
        state: (zipped.0.makeIterator(), zipped.1.makeIterator())
      ) { iterators in
        ((iterators.0.next(), iterators.1.next()) as Optional)
          .filter { $0 != nil || $1 != nil }
      }
    )
  }
}
```

```swift
public extension Optional {
  /// Exchange two optionals for a single optional tuple.
  /// - Returns: `nil` if either tuple element is `nil`.
  init<Wrapped0, Wrapped1>(_ optionals: (Wrapped0?, Wrapped1?))
  where Wrapped == (Wrapped0, Wrapped1) {
    switch optionals {
    case let (wrapped0?, wrapped1?):
      self = (wrapped0, wrapped1)
    default:
      self = nil
    }
  }
  
  /// Transform `.some` into `.none`, if a condition fails.
  /// - Parameters:
  ///   - isSome: The condition that will result in `nil`, when evaluated to `false`.
  func filter(_ isSome: (Wrapped) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Self {
    try flatMap { try isSome($0) ? $0 : nil }
  }
}
```

```swift
public func firstNonNil<Element>(_ tuple: (Element?, Element?)) -> Element? {
  switch tuple {
  case (let _0?, _):
    return _0
  case (nil, let _1?):
    return _1
  case (nil, nil):
    return nil
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can fill your smaller array with zeroes, then use `zip`. `inout` means that arrays are mutable, or you can make the copy of function parameters inside the function to make them mutable.

```
private func combineArrays(array1: inout [Int], array2: inout [Int]) -> [Int] {
    let maxSize = max(array1.count, array2.count)

    if (array1.count > array2.count) {
        array2.append(contentsOf: [Int](repeating: 0, count: maxSize - array2.count))
    } else if (array2.count > array1.count) {
        array1.append(contentsOf: [Int](repeating: 0, count: maxSize - array1.count))
    }

    return zip(array1, array2).map(+)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//javaScript
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
var array2 = [9,7,8,6,5,6,7];

let a= array1.length;
let b = array2.length;

var array3 = [];

let c = a>b?a:b;

for(let i=0; i<c; i++){
    if(i < a && i < b){
        array3.push(array1[i] + array2[i]);
    } else if(i >= a){
        array3.push(array2[i])
    } else{
        array3.push(array1[i])
    }
}

console.log(array3)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).